# Can we make "stepper" and "stepper-motor" synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Not much to say here really, the title really explains it. <strike>Unless they have different meanings, they are the same thing.</strike> [Facepalm because of a typo: kinda self implied. *If a, then a.*] *Correction:* **Unless I am mistaken, they are both the same exact thing and should be synonymized.** (Is that even a word?)

[stepper](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stepper) vs. [stepper-motor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stepper-motor) is like a [servo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servo) vs. [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor).

[By the way moderators feel free to edit the tags; it's hard to pick between [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging). Maybe I should start another post, but what to tag that...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you are right... Consider it done!

Answer (score 1):

Note that [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) vs. [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) is actually different to [stepper](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stepper) vs. [stepper-motor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stepper-motor).

The tag hierarchy for the [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) tag is:

- As explained in the [servos tag wiki](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/servos/info), the [servos](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servos) tag is only for questions which don't fit into a more specific category:

  - The [rcservo](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcservo) tag is for questions about hobby servos, see the [rcservo tag wiki](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/rcservo/info).
  - The [servomotor](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servomotor) tag is for questions about industrial servos, see the [servomotor tag wiki](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/servomotor/info).

As to the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) vs. [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) confusion, I have just fixed that too.

Comment: Thanks for the tagging fix... and yeah I forgot about that with the industrial/rc servo. Oops, well you got the point. :)